# $export is not a function

Tags: webpack, gulp, babeljs, laravel-elixir

I have the following error message, trying to use babel:

> "$export is not a function"

Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
require('laravel-elixir-vue');

elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.webpack('custom/index.js', 'public/compiled/app.js', false);

});

    Elixir.webpack.mergeConfig({
    babel: {
        presets: ['es2015'],
        plugins: ['transform-vue-jsx'],
    },
    module: {
        loaders:  [ {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'babel'
        }]
    }
});
```

When I do "gulp" everything seems to be ok, but I can see the error message in browser. I tried to exclude node-modules and it did not help.

P.S. Hope someone could help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of laravel? 5.3?